# WHERE IN clause in pymysql returns last row

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Consider a table **users** of 6 rows

```
   +_______________________+
   |     userid |  name    |
   +-----------------------+
   |       1    | john     |
   |       2    | steve    |
   |       3    | joe      |
   |       4    | jason    |
   |       5    | abraham  |
   |       6    | leonard  |
   +-----------------------+
```

I am using the below SQL query:

```
SELECT userid,name FROM users where userid IN (2,3,4,5);
```

which returns 4 rows -

```
   |       2    | steve    |
   |       3    | joe      |
   |       4    | jason    |
   |       5    | abraham  |
```

Pymysql equivalent code is as below:

```
def get_username(user_ids):
    data=[]
    conn = init_db()
    cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.executemany("SELECT userid,name from users WHERE userid IN (%s)",user_ids)
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        data.append([row['userid'],row['name']])
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return data

user_ids=[2,3,4,5]
get_usernames(user_ids)
```

This code just returns the last row [[5,abraham]] . How can I fetch all those rows?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the (partly documented) behaviour of `.executemany()`:

> Help on method executemany in module pymysql.cursors:
>
> executemany(self, query, args) method of pymysql.cursors.Cursor instance
>
> Run several data against one query
>
> :param query: query to execute on server
>
> :param args:  Sequence of sequences or mappings.  It is used as parameter.
>
> :return: Number of rows affected, if any.
>
> This method improves performance on multiple-row INSERT and
>      REPLACE. Otherwise it is equivalent to looping over args with
>      execute().

So what you want here is `cursor.execute()` - but then, you have a bit more work to build your SQL query:

```
user_ids = (2, 3, 4, 5)
placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(user_ids)) 
sql = "SELECT userid,name from users WHERE userid IN ({})".format(placeholders)
cursor.execute(sql, user_ids)
data = list(cursor)
```

Note that cursors are iterables, so you don't need to explicitely call `cursor.fetchall()` then iterate on the result, you can iterate directly on the cursor. Also note that if you want a list of `(id, name)` tuples, using a `DictCursor` is just a double waste of CPU cycles (once for building the dicts and once for rebuilding tuples out of them), you could just use a default cursor and return `list(cursor)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that is something related SELECT statement.
May you try this way of generating the query?

```
def get_username(user_ids):
    data=[]
    conn = init_db()
    cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.executemany("SELECT userid,name from users WHERE userid IN "+"("+','.join(str(e) for e in user_ids)+")")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        data.append([row['userid'],row['name']])
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return data

user_ids=[2,3,4,5]
get_usernames(user_ids)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It would be my guess, too, that we need a string for %s, not an array. So build the string from the array. (I don't know if this answer has it correct syntactically, though, as I don't know Python. Does it build a comma-separated string from the values? Anyway, the approach makes sense in my opinion.)

Comment: Why the downvote: you just bypassed the builtin protection against SQL injection, leaving your app opened for the first script kiddie. Read this for more on the topic: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: FYI: the "%s" placeholder in SQL queries passed to `cursor.execute()` is not (used as) a string formatting operator (and it's really a pity they choosed to use this as placeholder instead of a '?', as it obviously confuses everyone), it's, really, just a placeholder.

Comment: And finally: while we're talking about string formatting, please learn to use Python's formatting features, they make your code much more readable than string concatenation ;-)

Comment: Great answers Thank you both for the feedback!